# Move Object to the last position or position just outside the collision area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using a Player rigid body object and there are walls around the Player. These walls are restricting the Player to go through. The Player gets collided with these walls and then falls. The Player uses teleport function to jump from one area to next. Is there a way to make the Player jump to a position just outside the collision area after the Player is collided with these walls?
That is, Player A gets collided with the wall and does not jump to last position, but the position before the collision happened?

```
    public GameObject Player;
    public Vector3 PlayerPos;
    public bool RecordPos = true;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(RecordPos == true)
        {
            PlayerPos = Player.transform.position;
        }
        
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "Cube(3)" )
        {
            RecordPos = false;
            Player.transform.position = PlayerPos;
        }
    }
```

In this script, the Player moves to last position it teleported from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general when dealing with `Rigidbody` you shouldn't apply positions through the `Transform` component but rather through the `Rigidbody`.

I could imagine something like if you collide with a wall you get pushed away from the wall a bit in the direction where you came from like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private float someDistanceThreshold = 0.01f;

[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    PlayerPos = _rigidbody.position;
}

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    // instead of the name I would rather use a tag later to cover all obstacles
    if(col.gameObject.name == "Cube(3)")
    {
        _rigidbody.position -= (_rigidbody.position - PlayerPos).normalized * someDistanceThreshold;

        // For stopping the player here
        _rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this solution, since I am adding a rigidbody to my player component, the player gets bounced off after it gets hit by a wall. Should I set ```isKinematic = true``` once the collision occurs?

Comment: @Saif I guess that depends on your needs .. is the current behavior as expected or is there an issue with the answer?

Comment: It helps :) I will just deactivate and reactivate the ```isKinematic``` function once the collision occurs. Thank you.

Comment: If what you want to do is stopping the player you could also after the `_rigidbody.position ...` add a line `_rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;` which would make it not move anymore

Comment: Ah cool thanks for this. So can i again reset it after adding this line? So that the Player can still start colliding?

Comment: Through research I saw that using Physics material and setting the bounciness to 0 helps the Player not to bounce off. But I guess thats only in 2D since in 3D it did not work for me.

Comment: Actually it does not :( Well I have another thing in my mind. I will ask as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The "last" position before colliding is 1 frame before the collision. If you capture this position, the character will probably just fall on the obstacle again. Imagine you have a platform `___...___` and an obstacle. The easiest solution is to have 1 trigger at the left side of the obstacles and 1 trigger at the right side. If the player hasn't overcome the obstacle yet, he will be teleported to a chosen destination by you (before the obstacle) and if he's already overcome the obstacle, he will be teleported at the right side.  `__S_..._S__` (S stands for save/checkpoint trigger)

You need the following script on the gameobject with the Trigger collider. You also need to create a child object to the gameobject with the trigger:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
   SaveManager.Instance.LastCheckpointOnHit = transform.GetChild(0).position;
}
```

And I suppose you have some sort of a singleton for data persistance. Now you can move the child gameobject whereever you want to teleport the player. And BTW I named the property *LastCheckpoint**OnHit***, because I was thinking of Holow Knight where if you get hit by spikes it instantly teleports you.

Then you just move the player: `Player.transform.position = SaveManager.Instance.LastCheckpointOnHit;`